# Subset an imported xlsx in R without formula. subset gives error because of this

Tags: r, excel, subset

I am trying to subset a column in `R` from an `xlsx` file.
That particular column in excel is being used to plot a graph.
Because of which when I try to subset that column it gives an error.

> Error in subset.default(ds[, 2]) :    argument "subset" is missing,
>   with no default

This can be done by converting `xlsx` to `csv` or removing the graph but I want to solve this problem in `R`.

```
require(xlsx)
ds<-read.xlsx("Attachment-.xlsx", sheetName= "exchangeGBP", keepFormulas = FALSE)
ds<-subset(ds[,-1])
apply(ds,2,function)
```

The data looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Show your data and the other code you used to read it, please.

Comment: ds<-read.xlsx("Attachment.xlsx", sheetName= "exchangeGBP", keepFormulas = FALSE)
ds<-subset(ds[,-1])

Comment: Please post it in the question with a sample of your data.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), how to present your problems in SO. Welcome! Copy-pasting an image is a no-no here.

Comment: So, you want `ds` to have only the whole data in the column `GBP/EUR` or part of it? You want to subset based on what?

Comment: I want a subset with the GBP/EUR column only and it's giving me that error

Answer (score 0):

Just did it using ds <- ds$GBP.EUR
Although still not sure why subset is giving error.
Thanks anyway guys